If a rod rotating about its centre of mass is cut into 2 equal parts about its axis of rotation should its moment of inertia remain the same?
If a rod rotating about its centre of mass is cut into 2 equal parts about its axis of rotation, the moment of inertia should remain the same, right? And since $L$ and $M$ are halved, it should be
$$\frac{1}{12} \frac{M}{2} \left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{ML^2}{96},$$ right?
But actually we only halve the mass and not the length to get $\dfrac{ML^2}{24}$.
We know the moment of inertia of a half rod is $1/3 \, ML^2$. Here, halving mass and length gives $1/24 \, ML^2$.

I can't make out what this is trying to say.

The total moment of inertia will remain the same $1/12 \, ML^2$, but the moment of inertia of the two halves will be $1/24 \, ML^2$ each.
We can say that by taking the sum of both halves as equal to one or by applying the parallel axis theorem for each and getting $$I_{\text{half rod}} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{M}{2} \left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2$$ which finally gives $1/24 \, ML^2$.
Hope this helps...
